# Update entity which has file fields in Symfony2 (Doctrine)

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have an entity that is created through a form with file fields. Now when I want to update this entity through the same form, I need to reupload the files. How could I do to pre-fill the file fields or not modifiy these attributes when linving the fields blank?

EDIT : FormType :

```
class ThemeType extends AbstractType {

    private $edit;
    private $parentFunctionalId;

    public function __construct($parentFunctionalId = null, $edit = false) {
        $this->edit = $edit;
        $this->parentFunctionalId = $parentFunctionalId;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder->add('translations', 'collection', array('type' => new ThemeHasTranslationsType(),'allow_add' => true))
            ->add('image1', 'file', array(
                'data_class' => null, 'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('image2', 'file', array(
                'data_class' => null, 'required' => false
            ))
            ->add('style', new StyleType())
            ->add('isVerb', 'checkbox', array('label' => 'Verbe', 'required' => false))
            ->add('isActive', 'checkbox', array('label' => 'Activé', 'required' => false));

            $action = $this->parentFunctionalId != null ? $this->parentFunctionalId : '/app_dev.php/themes';
            $submitLabel = $this->edit ? 'edit' : 'create';
            $builder->setAction($action)
                    ->add($submitLabel, 'submit');

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MyApp\BusinessBundle\Entity\Theme'
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'translations';
    }

}
```

Comment: Please consult [this article from the Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html) and set `required` option to `false` for a corresponding form element.

Comment: Required is set to false, which means that file fileds are not blocking for submitting the forms. But if I submit whith blank file fields, it nulls the property of my entity. Reading the CookBook doc once again didn't help, maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: Make sure your `prePersist` and `preUpload` lifecycle callback(s) starts with `if ($this->file !== null)` which will skip the file upload if the form element send no data.

Comment: They do, but they don't seem to be triggered...

Comment: Could you paste the code of your form? Do you create it in a FormType class?

Comment: I edited the question with the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a second attribute `$image1Filename` containing the filename of the file uploaded.

This way, you can check if the form contains a file when posted, and "manually" handle the file upload (via lifecycle callbacks events eventually).